# filtering between two am pm time in postgres

Tags: postgresql, time, between

I have a filter for postgres

```sql
AND to_char(eat.datecreated, 'HH12:MI:SS AM') BETWEEN
  to_char('06:00:00', 'HH12:MI:SS AM') AND to_char('06:00:00', 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

and resulted :

```sql
ERROR:  function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 25: ...to_char(eat.datecreated, 'HH12:MI:SS AM') BETWEEN to_char('0...
                                                          ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique
SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 1455
```

Please, help me. I'm stuck with this query.

Comment: Note that for `timestamptz` the cast returns `time` according to your local time zone. This may or may not be what you want. You would have to define your requirements and the exact datatype in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
and eat.datecreated::time between '06:00:00'::time and '18:00:00'::time
```